# What is the continuity of these functions?

Tags: continuity

I need to find the continuity of the functions: $f(x)=[x]$, where [x] is the integer part and $f(x')=${x'}, where {x'} is the fractional part. I though about using series but if you could show me how or any other method it would be great.

Comment: Have you tried drawing these functions to see how they behave?

Comment: Yeah I know that they are not continuous on Z using that method. But I want to know one other than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a drawing of the floor function:

[image]

and here is one of the fractional part function (depending of your definition of it):

[image]

Now that you have an intuition about these functions, can you find where they are discontinuous?

Comment: Well I knew he was discontinuous on Z already by drawing. But I want to see other method. Like just writing or using series.

Comment: @OvyOvy Try limits :)

Comment: I would if I knew how. What limits?

Comment: $\lim_{x\to a^-} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a^+} f(x)$, and try to see if those limits equal $f(a)$

Comment: Well it depends. If a is integer then they are different. If not, then they are equal.

Comment: @OvyOvy There you go, and here is how you find the continuity.

Comment: Yeah but I found it by guessing. Isn't there any method that works for any function?

Comment: @OvyOvy There is not.

Comment: Ok then. Thanks.